# c# tabcontrol and grid problem

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

Hi i have a xaml code like this

```
    <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="test.Window1"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="Window1"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Button Content="Create a tab" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="49,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <TabControl Margin="0,63,0,0">

        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

in TabControl no tabItem there.
please helpe me, how to program with c# :
if i click the button, it will add a tab item with grid and a textblock in that. the result i wish like this :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Content="Create a tab" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="49,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <TabControl Margin="0,63,0,0">
        <TabItem Header="tab1">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="hi there" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

and if i click more that button, will continue add tab like that.

please help me (worship)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that this is your xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Content="Create a tab" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="49,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <TabControl Margin="0,63,0,0" x:Name="MyTabControl">
        <TabItem Header="tab1">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="hi there" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

you can add tabitem in codebehind like so:

```
TextBlock t = new TextBlock { Text= "hi" };
Grid g = new Grid;
g.Children.Add(t);
TabItem t = new TabItem();
t.Content = g;
MyTabControl.Children.Add(t);
```